# Workaround to return a value when an update failed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find a way to return the current the value of cell used as a condition for an update when that very same update happens to fail:

```sql
UPDATE public.streams
SET version = 1
WHERE id = '0171c6f4-7c44-43dd-ae85-530a77608d8e'::UUID
AND version = 0
RETURNING version
```

The problem of the code above is that `RETURNING` only works if the `UPDATE` succeeds, and I would like to get that regardless of the outcome (actually I'd like to get the value of `version` along with the outcome (as `TRUE` or `FALSE`), that is if the update failed or not).

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? It doesn't update the row because it can't find it, because of locking, time outs...?

Comment: Well I'm trying to get the value in case of an optimistic lock, not sure what I'm asking is actually doable without being out of sync.

Comment: Like say the client is willing to update version supposedly at version 3 with version 5, turns out the version is actually 4, so the update is miserably failing. In that case I would like to get a set with version (4 + FALSE).

Comment: Ah... thought so. You are trying to retrieve the value of "another row" (the current version) when it was updated. That's a different row.

Comment: Yea it is, in case of success 5 + TRUE, not sure this can actually be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In optimistic row locking, if you try to update a row already changed by another thread the update will fail, of course.

And now the current version of the row is actually *another row*, not the same one (at least for the database).

As a general rule you have two options:

- Consider your changes stale, and lose them by rolling back the whole transaction.
- Refresh the data and try to recover the new changes by merging both **new** versions of it, somehow.

It seems to me that you are trying to implement the latter. If this is the case, you'll need to *refresh* the data, and that necessarily mean to execute a brand new `SELECT`... separate from the failed `UPDATE` you tried. I don't think you can combine both into a single query.

Comment: thanks, the latter is actually what I'm already doing, just that I'm afraid it's not "atomic enough" if that makes any sense.

Comment: @KerryPerret Does it matter if it is atomic or not? Even if it were, then a nanosecond later another thread could update it again, and the data in your app will be stale again. Remember, the data/object in your app is always a **copy**, never the **original**.

Comment: you're right! Makes sense, thanks a lot for pointing this out.